# How can I make the function change the array index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

So I recently updated my image slider to use react hooks and now things have broken and I can't figure out why.

when I click the prev or the next I want the slider to change to the array with the correct index, but nothing happens. I can see that the index changes but I don't understand why it doesn't change to the new array. now its always on the array with index of 0.

What I tried:

- Removing the array index from sortIntoArray and using it directly in the map function. Both as number and as a string.

from this:

```
setImages(currenState => ({ ...currenState,
  posters: result[0]
}));

let poster = posters.map((item, index) => (<img src={item} alt="poster" style={style.poster}
key={index}/>));
```

to this

```
setImages(currenState => ({...currenState, 
  posters: result
}));

let poster = posters[1].map((item, index) => (<img src={item} alt="poster" style={style.poster} key={index} />   ));
```

and also

```
let poster = posters["1"].map((item, index) => (<img src={item} alt="poster" style={style.poster} key={index} />));
```

But If I do this I get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of
   undefined. This worked before I changed the component from a class
   component to to use hooks.

- I tried adding arguments to sortIntoArray and calling it directly from nextSlide and prevSlide.

I created a sandbox here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-firefly-wzxi0?file=/src/Slider.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly you need to update your use effect to have a depependency of your state instead of an empty array or else it will only execute your function once which means that you are only ever calling `sortIntoArray` with the initial state. So try something like

```
useEffect(() => {
    sortIntoArray();
  }, [images.idx]);
```

Which means that each time the `images.idx` state changes, it will call your effect again.

Secondly, in your `sortIntoArray` function, I found a bug where it would set `posters` to be a string instead of an array which would cause the `map of undefined` error.

I couldn't work out why you were trying to group the array into sections of 3 and then set posters to be the correct item from that array. So I've updated your `sortIntoArray` function to look like

```
const sortIntoArray = () => {
    let posterImages = [...images.items];

    let size = 3;

    let posters = posterImages.slice(
      images.idx * size,
      (1 + images.idx) * size
    );

    setImages(currenState => ({
      ...currenState,
      posters
    }));
  };
```

The difference here being that we just grab the right subsection using slice and set posters to be equal to that.

I also had to update your next function to the following based on the previous changes

```
const nextSlide = () => {
    let current = images.idx;
    let next = current + 1;

    let posterLength = Math.ceil(images.items.length / size) - 1;

    if (next > posterLength) {
      next = posterLength;
    }

    setImages(currentState => {
      return {
        ...currentState,
        idx: next
      };
    });
  };
```

With the difference here being that we simply just determining the poster length based on diving the total number of items by the size.

You can see this all here: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-snow-1cs0e?file=/src/Slider.js Is that what you're after?

Comment: I thought I answered here earlier, but it was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for taking your time to explain and help me. It's really appreciated.